# How to dynamically update an HTMLCollection using x and y coordinates

Tags: javascript, htmlcollection

I am working on a battleship game and I am trying to update the x and y coordinates on an HTMLCollection. The way I am trying to update is not working because I am accessing it as a 2d array when it is a 1d array.

```
// display.js
const displayCompAttk = () => {
const result = game.computer.sendAttack(game.player)

const x = result[0]
const y = result[1]

playerCells[x][y].textContent = result[2]
}
```

Meaning I can only update the x or y coordinates like so playerCells[x] or playerCells[y] and that is not what I want. Is there a possible way to update the x and y coordinates of the HTMLCollection to display true or false ?

```js
const createShip = (shipLength, name) => {
  const hits = 0
  let sunk = false

  function getLength() {
    return this.shipLength
  }

  function hit() {
    this.hits += 1
    return this.hits
  }

  function isSunk() {
    if (this.hits >= this.shipLength) {
      sunk = true
      return sunk
    }
    sunk = false
    return sunk
  }
  return {
    getLength,
    hit,
    isSunk,
    shipLength,
    name,
    hits,
  }
}

// gameboard.js

const Gameboard = () => {
  const rows = 10
  const columns = 10
  const board = []
  const missedCoord = []
  const shipArr = []
  const attackCoord = []
  const getBoard = () => [...board]

  const Water = () => {
    let isHit = false
    const hit = () => {
      isHit = true
    };
    return {
      type: "water",
      hit,
      get isHit() {
        if (isHit) {
          return "BLOOP! Miss."
        }
        return "Ship hit!"
      }
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i += 1) {
    board[i] = []
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j += 1) {
      board[i][j] = Water()
    }
  }

  // Need to reduce array amount to a single value
  const cellCount = getBoard().reduce((row, col) => row + col.length, 0)

  const validCoords = (x, y) => {
    if (x < 0) {
      return false
    }
    if (x > 9) {
      return false
    }
    if (y < 0) {
      return false
    }
    if (y > 9) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
  const shipIsInbounds = (x, y, ship) => {
    const shipsLength = ship.getLength()

    if (x + shipsLength > columns) {
      // console.log("Cannot place ship horizontally, out of bounds.");
      return false;
    }
    if (y + shipsLength > rows) {
      // console.log("Cannot place ship vertically, out of bounds.");
      return false;
    }
    return true
  }
  const doShipsCollide = (x, y, ship) => {
    const shipsLength = ship.getLength()
    const currentBoard = getBoard()
    for (let i = 0; i < shipsLength; i += 1) {
      if (currentBoard[x][y + i].type !== "water") {
        // console.log("Ships cannot overlap!")
        return false
      }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < shipsLength; i += 1) {
      if (currentBoard[x + i][y].type !== "water") {
        // console.log("Ships cannot overlap!")
        return false
      }
    }
    return true
  }
  const placeHorizontal = (x, y, ship) => {
    const shipsLength = ship.getLength()
    const currentBoard = getBoard()

    // Loop through ships length
    if (validCoords(x, y) && shipIsInbounds(x, y, ship) && doShipsCollide(x, y, ship)) {
      for (let i = 0; i < shipsLength; i += 1) {
        // Change ship.name back to ship
        currentBoard[x][y + i] = ship
        shipArr.push(ship)
      }
      return true
    }
    return false
  }
  const placeVertical = (x, y, ship) => {
    const shipsLength = ship.getLength()
    const currentBoard = getBoard()

    // Loop through ships length
    if (validCoords(x, y) && shipIsInbounds(x, y, ship) && doShipsCollide(x, y, ship)) {
      for (let i = 0; i < shipsLength; i += 1) {
        // Change ship.name back to ship
        currentBoard[x + i][y] = ship
        shipArr.push(ship)
      }
      return true
    }
    return false
  }

  function canShipBeHitAgain(x, y) {
    const coords = [x, y]
    const coordStr = JSON.stringify(coords)
    const attackCoordStr = JSON.stringify(attackCoord[0])

    if (coordStr === attackCoordStr) {
      console.log("Cannot hit same spot!")
      return false
    }
    return true
  }

  function receiveAttack(x, y) {
    const water = Water()
    const currentBoard = getBoard()

    if (canShipBeHitAgain(x, y) && validCoords(x, y) && currentBoard[x][y].hit()) {
      attackCoord.push([x, y])
      console.log(`Hit at coordinates ${[x]},${[y]}`)
      return true
    }
    water.hit()
    missedCoord.push([x, y])
    return false
  }

  function allSunk() {
    shipArr.every((ship) => {
      if (!ship.isSunk()) {
        console.log("All ships are not sunk.")
        return false
      }
      return false
    })
    return true
  }
  return {
    placeVertical,
    placeHorizontal,
    getBoard,
    cellCount,
    receiveAttack,
    allSunk,
    canShipBeHitAgain,
    validCoords,
    shipIsInbounds,
    doShipsCollide,
    attackCoord
  }
}

// player.js

const createComputer = () => {
  const computerGameboard = Gameboard()
  // console.log(computerGameboard.attackCoord)
  const arrayOfCoords = []
  const compAttkCoords = []
  let counter = 0

  const shuffleArray = (array) => {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]]
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j += 1) {
      arrayOfCoords.push([i, j]);
    }
  }

  shuffleArray(arrayOfCoords)

  const placeShipHorizontal = (ship) => {
    let x;
    let y;
    do {
      x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9));
      y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9));
    }
    while (computerGameboard.placeHorizontal(x, y, ship) === false);
    computerGameboard.placeHorizontal(x, y, ship)
  }

  const placeShipVertical = (ship) => {
    let x
    let y
    do {
      x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9))
      y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9))
    }
    while (computerGameboard.placeVertical(x, y, ship) === false)
    computerGameboard.placeVertical(x, y, ship)
  }

  const setEnemyBoard = (player) => player.getPlayerBoard

  const sendAttack = (player) => {
    const randomXCoords = arrayOfCoords[counter][0]
    const randomYCoords = arrayOfCoords[counter][1]

    compAttkCoords.push([randomXCoords, randomYCoords])

    const response = player.playerGameboard.receiveAttack(randomXCoords, randomYCoords)
    counter += 1;

    return [randomXCoords, randomYCoords, response]
  }

  return {
    computerGameboard,
    setEnemyBoard,
    placeShipHorizontal,
    placeShipVertical,
    sendAttack,
    compAttkCoords
  }
}

const createPlayer = (name) => {
  const getName = () => name
  const playerGameboard = Gameboard()
  // console.log(playerGameboard.attackCoord)

  const placeShipHorizontal = (x, y, ship) => playerGameboard.placeHorizontal(x, y, ship)

  const placeShipVertical = (x, y, ship) => playerGameboard.placeVertical(x, y, ship)

  const setEnemyBoard = (comp) => comp.getCompBoard

  const sendAttack = (x, y, comp) => comp.computerGameboard.receiveAttack(x, y)

  return {
    getName,
    placeShipHorizontal,
    placeShipVertical,
    setEnemyBoard,
    sendAttack,
    playerGameboard
  }
}

// game.js 

const createGame = () => {
  const player = createPlayer("Player")
  const computer = createComputer()

  const carrier = createShip(5, "Carrier")
  const battleship = createShip(4, "Battleship")
  const destroyer = createShip(3, "Destroyer")
  const submarine = createShip(3, "Submarine")
  const patrolBoat = createShip(2, "Patrol Boat")

  return {
    player,
    computer,
    carrier,
    battleship,
    destroyer,
    submarine,
    patrolBoat
  }
}

// display.js

const playerContainer = document.querySelector(".player-container")
const computerContainer = document.querySelector(".computer-container")
const compCells = document.getElementsByClassName("c-board-cell")
const playerCells = document.getElementsByClassName("p-board-cell")

const game = createGame()

const createPlayerDisplay = () => {
  const board = game.player.playerGameboard.getBoard()

  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i += 1) {
    board[i] = []
    for (let j = 0; j < board.length; j += 1) {
      const cell = document.createElement("td")
      cell.classList.add("p-board-cell")
      cell.setAttribute("x", i)
      cell.setAttribute("y", j)
      board[i][j] = cell
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr")
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j += 1) {
      row.append(board[i][j])
    }
    row.classList.add("p-board-row")
    playerContainer.append(row)
  }
}

createPlayerDisplay()

const createCompDisplay = () => {
  const board = game.computer.computerGameboard.getBoard()

  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i += 1) {
    board[i] = []
    for (let j = 0; j < board.length; j += 1) {
      const cell = document.createElement("td")
      cell.classList.add("c-board-cell")
      cell.setAttribute("x", i)
      cell.setAttribute("y", j)
      board[i][j] = cell
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr")
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j += 1) {
      row.append(board[i][j])
    }
    row.classList.add("c-board-row")
    computerContainer.append(row)
  }
}

createCompDisplay()


const displayPlayerAttk = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < compCells.length; i += 1) {
    compCells[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (compCells[i].textContent.includes("true" || "false")) {
        return false
      }
      const xPos = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("x")
      const yPos = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("y")
      compCells[i].textContent = game.player.sendAttack(Number(xPos), Number(yPos), game.computer)
      return true
    })
  }
}

displayPlayerAttk()

const displayCompAttk = () => {
  const result = game.computer.sendAttack(game.player)

  const x = result[0]
  const y = result[1]

  playerCells[x][y].textContent = result[2]
}


game.player.sendAttack(1, 2, game.computer)

game.computer.placeShipHorizontal(game.carrier)
game.computer.placeShipVertical(game.battleship)
game.player.placeShipHorizontal(1, 2, game.carrier)
game.player.placeShipVertical(6, 6, game.battleship)

displayCompAttk()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

td {
  border: black solid 1px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

tr {
  border: black solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="title">Battleship</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="main-container">
      <h1 class="computer-header">Player</h1>
      <table class="player-container"></table>
      <h1 class="computer-header">Computer</h1>
      <table class="computer-container"></table>
      <div class="ship-container">
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Frame challenge: aren't the board arrays already 2d arrays of `td` cells? Why not setup `const playerBoard = game.player.playerGameboard.getBoard()` instead of `playerCells` ?

Comment: Hey traktor yes the board arrays are already 2d arrays. Can you expand a bit what do you mean by `Why not setup const playerBoard = game.player.playerGameboard.getBoard() instead of playerCells` ? @traktor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Frame Challenge**

A confusing part of code is overwriting the variable `board` array content  in the create display functions. `board` initially contains a cloned 2D array of `Water` objects (to get its dimensions) but entries are overwritten with `td` elements used to create a board table in HTML.

In  `createPlayerDisplay` the 2D array of board elements is not saved or returned, but if  made a property of `player`, say `player.grid`, could be used to set HTML table cells using `x` and `y` coordinates.

**Possible patch**

1. Insert `game.player.grid = board;` at the end of the `createPlayerDisplay` function body
2. replace the last line of `displayCompAttk`, `playerCells[x][y].textContent = result[2]`, with

   ```
    game.player.grid[x][y].textContent = result[2]
   ```

Note I did not attempt to finish or debug the game further. With the patch the game ran without runtime errors and clicks on the "Computer" display board updated cells with "true" or "false".

**Conversion formula**

To update the linear `playerCells` array as asked in the title however, you could use the conversion formula

```
index = y * rowLength + x
```